# Why is injecting a Stateful Session bean in JSF/ CDI managed beans is considered bad?

Tags: session, jsf, ejb-3.0, httpsession

[Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent) mentions here that -

> If you are using `SFSB`, then you must `avoid` injecting them into classes
>   that are `multithreaded` in nature, such as `Servlets` and `JSF managed`
>   `beans` (you don't want it to be shared by all clients).

Moving swiftly on, [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) also put forwards the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req)-, but indirectly.

> ....use SFSB only when you want a real stateful `session` bean

Consider a Session Scoped Managed bean-

```
@SessionScoped
public class Bean{
     @EJB
     EjbBean ejbBean;
}
```

with

```
@Stateful
public class EjbBean{
}
```

But the above `SessionScoped` bean will be linked to `one` client only and as such will have `state/ instance variables` different from `other` session scoped bean. Subsequently, any `stateful EJB bean` will not be shared by other clients.

Please suggest on what the author implies when he says-

> you don't want it to be shared by all clients

I do perfectly understand the difference b/w `HttpSession` & the `session` word in `Stateless Session Bean`.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35009907

Comment: @BalusC: I know Http request, Http Session, but I am confused what exactly is HTTP CONNECTION. Is it Http Session only, or I am plain evidently wrong here?